# Can I show text from recieved SMS in toast or something similar?

Tags: android, text, sms, toast

I have an application for one mobile operator, for activating SMS and Data packets, and clicking on one of the buttons SMS request for checking amount of MB left in my Data packet is sent. Then i get SMS answer with this information. now my question is next : Can I make that text of recieved SMS is shown in a Toast, or similar ???

Comment: Yes, you can! http://i.imgur.com/FIEUn.jpg

Comment: Eni hint how ?? link on example maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

sure just use Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),text_of_smsMessage, length_that_you_want).show()

Comment: And this will show text of message i received back from my operator on screen ??

Comment: Not really... it requires a lot more code to capture the message. Thing is that it seems you have not researched about it... it is better when you have tried something, show your code, and ask questions about specific problems.

Comment: I read about it, but i did not find any clue, so I came here for an advice where and what to look ....